# KivyMD app crashes on mobile but works on computer

Tags: deployment, kivymd, buildozer

It's my first app using KivyMD and first time using Buildozer to deploy app on mobile.
But app which works perfectly on PC on windows, on laptop on Linux is not running on POCO mobile.
I've connected cell to pc with adb to check logs.
Apparently app crashes because:

```
  1:#: import StartScreen libs.baseclass.start_screen.StartScreen
  2:#: import SettingsScreen libs.baseclass.settings_screen.SettingsScreen
  3:#: import FormScreen libs.baseclass.form_screen.FormScreen
  4:#: import MatchInfoScreen libs.baseclass.match_info_screen.MatchInfoScreen
>>5:#: import FourthLeagueScreen libs.baseclass.fourth_league_form_screen.FourthLeagueScreen
  6:#: import RegionalLeagueScreen libs.baseclass.regional_league_form_screen.RegionalLeagueScreen

Unable to import package 'libs.baseclass.fourth_league_form_screen.FourthLeagueScreen'
```

App doesn't have any problems to run on PC, any idea what might be an issue here?

I tried to use Buildozer on windows instead of ubuntu but without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem wasnt with import but what packages has been used in imported file. I used package which didnt have support on mobile, it wasnt Pypi package.